# Limit Display of Data from Database to a particular Row

Tags: c#, html, mysql, sql

I currently have a database, and an MVC set up that is displaying the information in the database. The problem is that it creates a row on the webpage for each piece of data in the column that is being called. What I want it to do is, only display information related to a particular row. I have a column for ID and would like to do something like display this company where the ID = 1 but I'm not sure how to do that in block of c# code inside of a cshtml file.

This is what I currently have and is creating 9 company rows and 9 name rows, but I only want one of each:

```
<table>
    @{
        Model.BallDataList = Model.BallDataList.OrderBy(x => x.ID).ToList();
        foreach(BallData row in Model.BallDataList)
        {
                <tr>
                    <td><b>Company: </b></td>
                    <td>@row.Company</td>
                </tr> 
                <tr>
                    <td><b>Name: </b></td>
                    <td>@row.Name</td>
                </tr> 
        }
    }
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure which one you want.

To display only unique IDs :

```
var ballData = Model.BallDataList.
    .GroupBy(x => x.ID).Select(g => g.First())
    .OrderBy(x => x.ID);
foreach(var row in ballData)
{ /*...*/ }
```

To display only those ID is 1 :

```
var ballData = Model.BallDataList.
    .Where(x => x.ID == 1)
    .OrderBy(x => x.ID);
foreach(var row in ballData)
{ /*...*/ }
```

I've changed the code a little so the sorting and filtering won't actually affect your model's state.

Comment: I used the bottom example that you posted and got the following error: "CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'bool'"

Comment: Sorry, it should be a double equal in the where clause.

Comment: Ok. I'm not sure if you have an answer to a follow up question, but I can't seem to find any references to the problem I am having. I created a table on my webpage and filled in the info using the code above with "ID == 1". Then I created another table and tried to fill it in using "ID == 2" but the second table stays blank. Is there any reason why an ID other than 1 would not work?

Comment: First thing you need to assert is whether or not `BallDataList` contains what you want. Do a test, `var result = BallDataList.Any(x => x.ID == 2);`, and check the value of the result.

Comment: The debugger says - "Name: Result, Value: False, Type: Bool".

Comment: In this case, `BallDataList` does not contains any record where ID is 2.  You need look into the source of `BallDataList`.